# psql \i metacommand with arguments

Tags: postgresql, psql

I have a sql script which i run for by-hand status checks of a long running process. My server is currently postgres 10. The script contains a couple dozen queries. However, each query requires the id of the current process (not linux pid, but a column in the db).

So, it's like

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id = 'xxx';
SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE id = 'xxx';
... and so forth
```

I have a sql script that i keep updating with the most recent id, and run with

```
db# \i my-script.sql
```

It would be great if I could pass variables into the script. For example, maybe the script is

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id = '$1';
SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE id = '$1';
```

and i could run

```
db# \i my-script.sql 'xxx'
```

and it would properly substitute that value for all `$1` in the sql script. Bonus points for multiple args (eg `$2` and so on).

OTOH, I could write a bash script wrapping psql command line, but I'd need to drop to a shell to execute it - if i'm already in psql, I'm right there.

Any advice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `psql` variables.

In the script, write

```
\prompt 'Please enter id:' myid
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id = :'myid';
```

If you don't want an interactive prompt, omit the `\prompt` and set the variable in the calling script:

```
\set myid 1234
```